# Placing FileUpload method in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The answer might be too easy for professioanl C# programmers, but this is a little tricky for me as I'm new to C# and ASP.NET MVC.

I've just learned about Strategy Design Patterns. My program requires to be able to upload images. I'm going to accomplish this in two ways, (1) to be able to upload to file system, and (2) upload to database. For that purposes, i'm going to use strategy design pattern for those two algorithms.

The problem is I'm implementing Strategy in a separate class library, other than MVC application Project in the solution.

**And this code, which worked fine in controller, is not working in the class library.**

This was in controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public void UploadFile() {
        string physicalPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../") + "UploadImages" + "\\";

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++) {

            Request.Files[0].SaveAs(physicalPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName));
        }
    }
```

And this is in class library.

```
public class UploadToFile : IUpload {
    public void Upload() {
        string physicalPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../") + "UploadImages" + "\\";
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++) {
            Request.Files[0].SaveAs(physicalPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName));
        }
    }
}
```

May be a class library cannot access the `HttpContext` and `Request`?

`using System.Web.Mvc;` and `using System.Web;` are referenced correctly.

I know the answer should be easy, which I couldn't found a good escalation of this topic while googleing for 30 minutes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class library you need to use [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)

So.. to access MapPath... use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
```

to access Request... use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Please note that you can use **HttpContext.Current** anywhere in your code, but you should verify that is not NULL (just in case it is not in a web context).

FYI: in a Web/MVC app the **Page.Context** property points to the same place as **HttpContext.Current**

Hope it helps.